# Expand all collapsed table rows in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive which I use to expand and collapse a data row within a table:

```
 angular.module('rokoApp')
      .directive('dir', function() {                                    
            return {
                link: function(scope, elem) {
                    $(elem).on('click', function() {
                    $(this)
                    .parent('tr')
                    .next('tr')
                    .toggle();
                });
           }
       };
   });
```

and here is the ng-repeat code:

```
 <tr ng-repeat-start="data in totalsum" ng-click="isRowCollapsed=!isRowCollapsed">
      <td>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{data.total | number:2}}">
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr ng-repeat-end ng-show="data.breakdown.length>0" ng-hide="isRowCollapsed">
      <td ng-show="data.breakdown.length>0">
           <div class="subvalues" ng-repeat="subvalues in data.breakdown">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{subvalues.subtotal | number:2}}">
           </div>
      </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>
           <input class="form-control" placeholder="{{getTotal('total') | number:2}}">
      </td>
 </tr>
```

I wish to expand all hidden data rows when one is clicked.

Comment: What is totalsum? What is data.breakdown? Where are you using the dir directive?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do here but I would say that there is no need for the directive. You should be able to get the same result by manipulating the data and using `ng-show` and `ng-hide` without using jQuery.